# Closed superstrings IIA and IIB (7.22) of Clifford Johnson's book

Tags: string-theory, tensor-calculus, spinors

In (7.22) the massless sectors is shown as
\begin{equation}
\text{IIA}:\; 
  (\bf{8}_\text{v}\oplus\bf{8}_\text{s})\otimes
  (\bf{8}_\text{v}\oplus\bf{8}_\text{c});\;\;
\text{IIB}:\;
  (\bf{8}_\text{v}\oplus\bf{8}_\text{s})\otimes
  (\bf{8}_\text{v}\oplus\bf{8}_\text{s}).
\end{equation}

The product of two representation gives (cf. Appendix B of Polchinski's ``STRING THEORY")
\begin{align}
\bf{2}^k\times\bf{2}^k 
= \begin{cases}
[1] + [3] + \cdots + [k+1]_{+}\\
[0] + [2] + \cdots + [k+1]_{+}
\end{cases},\;
{\bf{2}^k}'\times{\bf{2}^k}' 
= \begin{cases}
[1] + [3] + \cdots + [k+1]_{-}\\
[0] + [2] + \cdots + [k+1]_{-}
\end{cases},\;
\bf{2}^k\times{\bf{2}^k}'
= \begin{cases}
[0] + [2] + \cdots + [k]\\
[1] + [3] + \cdots + [k]
\end{cases},
\end{align}
where for all cases the first row indicates $k$ even cases while the second row indicates $k$ odd cases.

I thought by applying these formula for $k=3$ case, we can obtain (7.23) as
\begin{equation}
\bf{8}_\text{v}\otimes\bf{8}_\text{v}
= \bf{8}_\text{s}\otimes\bf{8}_\text{s}
= \bf{2}^3\times\bf{2}^3
= [0] + [2] + [4]_{+}
= \bf{1}\oplus\bf{28}\oplus\bf{35}
\end{equation}
in the NS-NS sector.
In the R-R sector
\begin{equation}
\text{IIA}:\;
\bf{8}_\text{s}\otimes\bf{8}_\text{c}
= \bf{2}^3\times{\bf{2}^3}'
= [1] + [3]
= \bf{8}_\text{v} + \bf{56}_\text{t},\;\;
\text{IIB}:\;
\bf{8}_\text{s}\otimes\bf{8}_\text{s}
= \bf{2}^3\times\bf{2}^3
= [0] + [2] + [4]_{+}
= \bf{1}\oplus\bf{28}\oplus\bf{35}.
\end{equation}

(1)
Here I have a question that what does mean subscript $t$ in the IIA theory.

(2)
Finally in the NS-R and R-NS sectors,
\begin{equation}
\bf{8}_\text{v}\otimes\bf{8}_\text{c}
= \bf{2}^3\times{\bf{2}^3}'
= [1] + [3]
= \bf{8}_\text{s} + \bf{56}_\text{c},\;\;
\bf{8}_\text{v}\otimes\bf{8}_\text{s}
= \bf{2}^3\times{\bf{2}^3}'
= [1] + [3]
= \bf{8}_\text{c} + \bf{56}_\text{s}.
\end{equation}
How can we identified it is $\bf{8}_\text{s}$ or $\bf{8}_\text{c}$ in the righthand side?

Comment: Probably $t$ for tensor multiplet?

Comment: I thought it is a rank three tensor and its dimension is 56

Comment: But how to identify this decomposition? “8 + 56.”